# Is there any way to get Jython support in VIM / gVIM?

Tags: vim, ide, editor, jython, sikuli

Does anybody know how to get Jython support in VIM / gVIM? (preferably on windows or alternatively on mac)

By Jython support I mean code completion, syntax highlighting etc. especially when working with third party .jar files (e.g. sikulixapi.jar from Sikuli /SikuliX).

Thanks in advance.

Cheers 
Tset Noitamotua

Comment: Could it be realized with this Plugin for Vim: [YouCompleteMe](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/)?

Comment: @Valloric: what do you as ycm masters think? :)

Comment: @Haroogan: what do you as ycm for windows master think? ;-)))

Comment: If the Jedi Python semantic engine (which YCM uses) can understand Jython, then YCM should work just fine with it. But I doubt Jedi supports Jython.

Comment: I do not understand the intention for using Vim, when there are full featured IDE's that support Python/Jython projects like Eclipse/PyDev, PyCharms ... and looking for an editor only, that has excellent support for adding your private features: Jedit. (ok, no code completion :-)

Comment: @RaiMan [Here´s my intention](https://github.com/Tset-Noitamotua/Sikuli-and-Robot-Framework-Integration/issues/4#issuecomment-72856441) :-)))

I would like to have SikuliX + Robot Framework in a lightweight, fast and highly customizable "ITE" (Integrated Testing Environment) - open source of course :)

Comment: Seems that there are not a lot vim-guys using jython and vise versa :-(